# Slow MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The following SQL query takes approximately **1 min. 15 sec.** to execute when entered directly into the SQL console. There are **6636 records in the qv_attribute table**.

Is the execution time for this query normal? Is there any way to reduce the time it takes to run this operation by changing database settings or optimizing the query?

```
SELECT a.node_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN(b.att_id = 9003) THEN a.att_description END) AS 'ICS_Owner',
MAX(CASE WHEN(b.att_id = 9004) THEN a.att_description END) AS 'Service',
MAX(CASE WHEN(t.rel_id = 12092) THEN t.att_description END) AS 'Contact_Name',
MAX(CASE WHEN(t.rel_id = 12610) THEN t.att_description END) AS 'Address_1',
MAX(CASE WHEN(t.rel_id = 9007) THEN t.att_description END) AS 'Address_2',
MAX(CASE WHEN(t.rel_id = 12612) THEN t.att_description END) AS 'City',
MAX(CASE WHEN(t.rel_id = 12614) THEN t.att_description END) AS 'State',
MAX(CASE WHEN(t.rel_id = 13508) THEN t.att_description END) AS 'a',
MAX(CASE WHEN(t.rel_id = 13509) THEN t.att_description END) AS 'b',
MAX(CASE WHEN(b.att_id = 13132) THEN a.att_description END) AS 'Description',
MAX(CASE WHEN(des.node_id = 10824) THEN des.att_description END) AS 'Row_Description'
FROM `qv_attribute` t, `qv_attribute` a, `qv_attribute` b, `qv_attribute` des
        WHERE b.att_id IN (9003,9004,13132,14542)
        AND b.att_name = a.att_name
        AND ((a.node_id = 1554 AND
                ((t.node_id = 1776 AND des.att_order = 1)
                OR (t.node_id = 1780 AND des.att_order = 2)
                OR (t.node_id = 1781 AND des.att_order = 3)
                OR (t.node_id = 1782 AND des.att_order = 4)
                OR (t.node_id = 1783 AND des.att_order = 5)
                OR (t.node_id = 1784 AND des.att_order = 6)
                OR (t.node_id = 1778 AND des.att_order = 7)
                OR (t.node_id = 1777 AND des.att_order = 8)))
            OR (a.node_id = 1574 AND
                ((t.node_id = 1574 AND des.att_order = 1)
                OR (t.node_id = 1779 AND des.att_order = 2)
                OR (t.node_id = 1576 AND des.att_order = 3)
                OR (t.node_id = 1577 AND des.att_order = 4)
                OR (t.node_id = 1710 AND des.att_order = 5)
                OR (t.node_id = 1711 AND des.att_order = 6)
                OR (t.node_id = 1712 AND des.att_order = 7)))
            OR (a.node_id = 1803 AND
                ((t.node_id = 1838 AND des.att_order = 1)
                OR (t.node_id = 1839 AND des.att_order = 2)
                OR (t.node_id = 1840 AND des.att_order = 3)
                OR (t.node_id = 1805 AND des.att_order = 4)))
            OR (a.node_id = 1831 AND
                ((t.node_id = 1842 AND des.att_order = 1)
                OR (t.node_id = 1847 AND des.att_order = 2)
                OR (t.node_id = 1833 AND des.att_order = 3)
                OR (t.node_id = 1848 AND des.att_order = 4)
                OR (t.node_id = 1845 AND des.att_order = 5)
                OR (t.node_id = 1846 AND des.att_order = 6)
                OR (t.node_id = 1841 AND des.att_order = 7)
                OR (t.node_id = 1844 AND des.att_order = 8)
                OR (t.node_id = 1843 AND des.att_order = 9)))
            OR (a.node_id = 1810 AND
                ((t.node_id = 1854 AND des.att_order = 1)
                OR (t.node_id = 1849 AND des.att_order = 2)
                OR (t.node_id = 1851 AND des.att_order = 3)
                OR (t.node_id = 1853 AND des.att_order = 4)
                OR (t.node_id = 1852 AND des.att_order = 5)
                OR (t.node_id = 1812 AND des.att_order = 6)
                OR (t.node_id = 1850 AND des.att_order = 7))))
        GROUP BY a.node_id,  t.node_id
```

EXPLAIN EXTENDED:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | des   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 6695 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | range | node_id       | node_id | 4       | NULL |  629 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | range | node_id       | node_id | 4       | NULL |  139 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Kindly include `EXPLAIN EXTEND YOUR_SLOW_QUERY` too...

Comment: You need to find a better approach than the unrelated tuple from t.node_id and des.att_order

Comment: @OMG : exactly the point of my answer, by putting those tuples in a table they become related, then they can just be joined on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you're not specifying any join conditions for t or des, and you makeing tons of comparisons to them.  So you're repeating every match of a and b with every combination of t and des, which is probably not what you're intending.

The resulting table has the number of rows equal to (a join b) * t * des

Here's what your where clause is boiling down to:

```
AND ((a.node_id = 1554 AND
  ((t.node_id IN 1776, 1780, 1781, 1782, 1784, 1778, 1777) AND des.att_order BETWEEN 1 AND 8)
OR (a.node_id = 1574 AND
  ((t.node_id IN 1779, 1576, 1577, 1710, 1711, 1712) AND des.att_order BETWEEN 1 AND 7)
```

...

That query is pretty ugly, but at ~7k rows a pivot with a bunch of filters shouldn't take over a minute

Comment: Thanks PMV, your answer was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Just think of the magic you could do if you created a table that looked like this:

```
a_node_id   t_node_id  att_order 
 1554          1776        1
 1554          1780        2
 1554          1781        3
 1554          1782        4
 1554          1783        5
 1554          1784        6
 1554          1778        7
 1554          1777        8

 1574          1574        1
 1574          1779        2
 1574          1576        3
 1574          1577        4
 1574          1710        5
 1574          1711        6
 1574          1712        7

 1803          1838        1
 1803          1839        2
 1803          1840        3
 1803          1805        4

 etc
```

Additional hint : Put this in a table and left join to this table -- much faster than the where clause you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have indexed your table - the slowdown comes from your `CASE WHEN` combinations. Split it into 11 separate queries and you'll observe a speedup.

On a side note, if you have to run this query often enough where 1 minute is too long - you may want to look into redesigning the database structure to keep some redundant, but quick-query information.

Good luck!

Comment: The problem could also be in the crazy where statement.